# Why does SpEL not work in Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Stream @SendTo

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-el, spring-cloud-stream

I have created the following code and matching configuration. The ingest of messages works great, but the `SpEL` is not evaluated at all, thus a new Exchange with the expression as a name is created...

Looking at my dependencies versions the `@SendTo` annotation SHOULD support this kind of expression...

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using `RabbitMQ` and `Spring Boot 1.4.3`

```
@EnableBinding(CommandChannel.class)
public class CommandSink {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommandSink.class);

    @StreamListener(CommandChannel.INPUT)
    @SendTo("!{request.messageProperties.headers['reply_to']}")
    public String processCommand(@Payload String cmd, @Header("reply_to") String replyToQueue){
        LOGGER.info("Got a {} command and I'll reply to {}", cmd, replyToQueue);
        String result = "geil: " + cmd;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing; there is simply no code in the bean post processor to evaluate a SpEL expression there; the value is a simple string value for the destination (channel name).

What leads you to believe SpEL is supported there? I am having trouble parsing this...

> Looking at my dependencies versions the @SendTo annotation SHOULD support this kind of expression...

Comment: Spring Stream for RabbitMQ is based on Spring Amqp. And that documentation clearly states this:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#async-annotation-driven-reply

Comment: You are conflating two different technologies. That is in the context of a `@RabbitListener`; a `@StreamListener` is a different beast. While SCSt can use RabbitMQ as a transport; that is but one option (Kafka etc). The `@StreamListener` knows nothing about RabbitMQ. You can, of course, use a `@RabbitListener` instead; in that case you don't need logic to pick off the replyTo - it will be used automatically, `@SendTo` is only used for messages that don't have a `replyTo`. I am not saying `@StreamListener` couldn't do something similar, but it would be more complex because of other transports.

Comment: Ah, I see. But then I have to manage creation of queues etc myself... I guees I'll just do the response sending "by hand". Thanks!